I am trying to land on a software engineering job. I have 2 degrees: one in hardware (BS EE) and another in software (BS SE)
I am a self-supporting individual whose education is earned through schooling while working. Back in the 90s I entered the STEM job market with an AAS degree in Digital Electronics. I worked in the capacity of a product support technician where I debugged daily "in-process" manufacturing failures. While doing technician job I saw many engineers about my age in the R&D sector of my company and gave myself another push to bridge my academic gap from the AAS degree and worked my way into a BS degree in EE (Electrical Engineering) field.
I became an EE shortly after my graduation and worked in that capacity for a long time. I then decided to change my career into software engineering in 2015. I decided to return to academia to work on my BS degree in Software Engineering. I graduated from ASU with a BS in Software Engineering in 2019 and re-entered the workforce not as a software engineer but rather a production system test engineer where I did a good amount of software development in Ruby, Python, Java, and C#. I applied my academic training in software engineering while working this job, following the standard software engineering workflow in all of these application development tasks using JAMA (for design specification, Jira for bug tracking, and Jenkins for automation testing), but my job title was System Test Engineer because I tested hardware systems to ensure they meet all specs prior to shipping out the door. I am no longer with this company.
How can I land on a pure software engineering job (Entry-level/Junior Dev, or Software Testing/QA)? I even prepared myself with an ISTQB certificate in hope to land on a software testing position, but so far I had bad luck. The code interview showed that ASU did not include Data Structure and Algorithm in their curriculum, and I had to learn that on my own. I did well with software construction type of questions, but the code interview always killed me. I can really use your advise here. Please throw your kind words my way.

Honestly, you have lots of experiences with system tests. Many companies are looking for these skills. You don't really have to switch to software development (unless that is your new career goal because it is inspirational to you).

If you want to study Data Structures and Algorithms, there are many websites that teach you how to prepare for those coding interviews. You can google to find out more info. For example, one good website that has video trainings along with coding explanations is : algoexpert.io/questions . Another is leetcode.com --- NOTE: I am not associated with these 2 websites in any way, shape or form. I just used them in the past.

You have 30+ years of experience and are trying to land a entry level job. That's going to be a tough sell. Have you considered looking for something that leverages your past work experience and education? Low level embedded software comes to mind here.

If you take an entry level job now, you will get a big pay cut because you will have an entry-level salary. Even if you want to take an entry level salary, the companies may not be willing to hire you because they think that sooner or later, you will quit this entry level job to go for a bigger salary else where.

First off, having a non-traditional background for an entry level position means that you are most likely to find such a job with a non-traditional company. That means looking at startups, doing gig work for small businesses, or finding a "transitional" position in a larger company. These all take a lot of work on the networking, marketing, and selling of yourself.
What it does mean is that looking for "a pure software engineering job" at a large Seattle based software company is not a realistic expectation.
One major challenge to these kinds of career changes is expecting high compensation at first. Often, we have to accept a far lower compensation than we have grown used to getting.
